# icloud.com like form input fields

Tags: jquery, css, forms, input

How do I make an input-field like seen on [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com/) ?

I want the placeholder to stay until someone starts typing. Is there a way with jQuery to accomplish this?

Comment: Please note which browser you wanna support.

Answer (score 2):

You may be referring to a **watermark** feature.

> A watermark typically appears as light gray text within an input or textarea element whenever the element is empty and does not have focus. This provides a hint to the user as to what the input or textarea element is used for, or the type of input that is required.

[image: watermark]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://jquery-watermark.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery-watermark/wiki/sample-watermark.png))</sub>

If this is the case you may want give a try to **[jquery-watermark](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-watermark)**. It supports [HTML5 "placeholder"](https://html5tutorial.info/html5-placeholder.php) capabilities natively (in browsers that support it) and gracefully degrades in other/older versions.

**Note:** Many other plugins exist. [Googling 'jquery watermark'](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20watermark) or ['jquery placeholder'](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20placeholder) will help you find them :)

**Note 2:** In order to be as compatible as possible, Apple *doesn't* rely on the HTML5 placeholder attribute and simply leverages JQuery to hide an overlapping div when the user starts typing.

Comment: @mkampitsch Glad to read this fit your need. As this answer seemed helpful, would you consider [upvoting/marking this question as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)?

Answer (score 0):

Read "HTML5 Placeholder Input Fields Fixed with jQuery" - http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Placeholder Attribute?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Example Placeholder" />
```

Comment: yeah I know the placeholder attribute, but it disappears when :focus is given…

Comment: @mkampitsch not in webkit browsers…

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the [placeholder](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=html%20placeholder%20english&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDoQFjAC&url=http://html5tutorial.info/html5-placeholder.php&ei=uR8UT9HcDJCyhAfskai1Ag&usg=AFQjCNHlrXuusO1c6ofyOELHmtDXItuEOA&cad=rja) attribute

```
<input type="text" id="user" name="user" placeholder="Please type your username" />
```

EDIT

ok, now i understood your problem: according to the previous code, you just need to bind keydown and check if the value is user's value or the default value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#user').keydown(function(e){
        if($(this).val()=='Please enter your username'){
            $('#user').val('');
        }
    });

    $('#user').focusout(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ''){
            $(this).val('Please enter your username');
        }
     });
});
```

test it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/G7s9u/41/

Comment: the placeholder doesn't stay when :focus is given